# python argparse: default flag

Tags: python, python-3.x

My script needs to take exactly two arguments. The third one below is what I am struggling with.

`python myscript -e arg1 arg2`

`python myscript -i arg1 arg2`

`python myscript arg1 arg2`

I could easily get the first two to work using `argparse` but I couldn't figure out how to get the third one to work with argparse. Basically, when no flag is specified, I would like to do same processing as with `-e` flag specified. The script should error out if exactly 2 arguments haven't been specified.

I checked python documentation and saw that there is a way to specify a default value to a flag but I couldn't find a way to make the argument itself; a default one.

`parser.add_argument('',nargs=2)`

Although a newbie to python, I knew it was dumb to try the above thing, but somehow hoped that magically it would work. :)

Could someone help me find a way to get the no-argument case to work?
Thanks

Comment: So... did you add an `arg1` and an `arg2` argument?

Comment: `parser.add_argument('input', nargs=2)`

Comment: In the first 2 cases, do you think of `arg1 arg2` as arguments to the `-e` or `-i` flags, or are they positional arguments as in the third?  Does the order matter?

Comment: @hpaulj: Yes the order does matter. I am doing some text manipulation on the files and `arg1` is treated as the source file and `arg2` is my destination file. `-e` and `-i` are flags that tell me whether the files are external or internal to a module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `arg1` and `arg2` required positional arguments:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-e', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-i', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument("arg1")
parser.add_argument("arg2")

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Usage:

```
$ python test.py value1 value2 --help
usage: test.py [-h] [-e] [-i] arg1 arg2

positional arguments:
  arg1
  arg2

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -e
  -i
```

Comment: Thanks alecxe. That's what I was looking for!